# GENEXUS: Importar archivo Excel desde campo Blob en Gx17U4

Tags: genexus

Tengo una KB con varios WP que tienen una variable tipo Blob para seleccionar un archivo Excel. Luego de seleccionar y verificar que dicha variable tiene el nombre de algun archivo &varBlob.FileName voy a un PRC que recibe dicha variable. En el source del PRC lo primero que hago es: &ExcelDocument.Open(&varBlob) y me salta el error 10 (Could not Open file No se admite el formato especificado en la ruta de acceso). Les cuento que hasta Gx17U3 esto me funcionaba perfecto. Algún comentario? Gracias Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

La variable blob de un archivo subido contiene una referencia gxupload: al archivo, no el path, por ejemplo "gxupload:ec6956e4d6a044b7a1af4414476f8321"

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?48242,Security%20improvements%20in%20upload%20mechanisms

Si se usa esa variable en el método ExcelDocument.open no se abre el archivo.

Es posible recuperar el path mediante el tipo File o el Cache, por ejemplo con el siguiente código:

```
&BlobRef = &BlobId.Replace(!"gxupload:",!"")
&Cache = Cache.GetCache(!"FL")
&BlobData.FromJson(&Cache.Get(&BlobRef))
```

Answer (score 0):

Me encontré con el mismo problema en la 17 U6, lo pude solucionar de la siguiente manera:

En lugar de hacer:

```
&ExcelDocument.Open(&Blob)
```

Tuve que agregar una variable &File de tipo de dato File y hacer:

```
&File.Source = &Blob
&ExcelDocument.Open(&File.GetURI())
```

Con esto me funcionó correctamente.
Como indica @Chona, esto es por una nueva mejora de seguridad a partir de la 17 U4.